# JUDDI inquiry (find) for access point

Tags: wsdl, find, access-point, juddi

I need to find or do an inquiry for getting the access point using JUDDI from an already published service. I followed the procedure told in [Apache jUDDI: Finding Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991920/apache-juddi-finding-templates). But it didn't work out and i get the following error from the Tomcat server:

```
Sep 01, 2012 11:29:58 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
INFO: Application {urn:uddi-org:v3_service}UDDIInquiryService#{urn:uddi-org:v3_service}find_service has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.juddi.v3.error.FatalErrorException: At least one name, categoryBag, find_tModel or tModelBag or name must be supplied
```

And also the same error is indicated in Netbeans IDE as:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: At least one name, categoryBag, find_tModel or tModelBag or name must be supplied
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
        FindService fs = new FindService();
        fs.setAuthInfo(rootAuthToken.getAuthInfo());
        fs.setBusinessKey("uddi:juddi.apache.org:e7180bfb-3c36-451e-86aa-f7605a96587c");
        ServiceList sl = inquiry.findService(fs);
        ServiceInfos si = sl.getServiceInfos();
        GetServiceDetail gsd = new GetServiceDetail();
        ServiceDetail sd = inquiry.getServiceDetail(gsd);
        BusinessService bs = (BusinessService) sd.getBusinessService();
        BindingTemplates bts = bs.getBindingTemplates();
        BindingTemplate bt = (BindingTemplate) bts.getBindingTemplate();
        AccessPoint ap = bt.getAccessPoint();
        wsdlTA.setText(ap.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it solved through the Apache JUDDI's project mailing list. Thanks to 秦玉珠 for the help. The code can be as follows:

```
ServiceList list1=inquiryService.findService(findservice);
GetServiceDetail gsd=new GetServiceDetail();
for(ServiceInfo serviceInfo :list1.getServiceInfos().getServiceInfo()){
    gsd.getServiceKey().add(serviceInfo.getServiceKey());
    System.out.println(serviceInfo.getServiceKey());
    String servicekey=serviceInfo.getServiceKey();

    GetServiceDetail getServiceDetail=new GetServiceDetail();
    getServiceDetail.setAuthInfo(authinfo);
    getServiceDetail.getServiceKey().add(servicekey);
    ServiceDetail serviceDetail=inquiryService.getServiceDetail(getServiceDetail);
    BusinessService businessservice=serviceDetail.getBusinessService().get(0);
    System.out.println("fetched service name:"+businessservice.getName().get(0).getValue());
    String bindingkey = businessservice.getBindingTemplates().getBindingTemplate().get(0).getBindingKey();
    System.out.println(bindingkey);

    GetBindingDetail gbd = new GetBindingDetail();
    gbd.setAuthInfo(authinfo);
    gbd.getBindingKey().add(bindingkey);
    BindingDetail bindingdetail=inquiryService.getBindingDetail(gbd);
    BindingTemplate bindingtemplate=bindingdetail.getBindingTemplate().get(0);
    String accesspoint=bindingtemplate.getAccessPoint().getValue();
    System.out.println(accesspoint);
}
```